# If every subsequence of a sequence has a convergent subsequence then sequence is bounded or not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In this question, for statement 1 i've proved that the later sequence is bounded and hence has a convergent subsequence.

For statement 2, i tried to construct a counter-example but i couldn't. So i suspect it is true and if it is then how to prove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_2$ is true. Let us prove this by contradiction. If $(a_n)$ is not bounded the there is a subsequence which tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. And this subsequence does not have any convergent subsequence.

More details: for any $n$ there exists $k_n$ such that $|a_{k_n}| >n$ and we may assume that $k_n$ are increasing. Either $a_{k_n}>n$ for infinitely many $n$ or $a_{k_n}<-n$ for infinitely many $n$ so (by going to a subsequence) we may assume that $a_{k_n}>n$ for all $n$. Now consider $(a_{k_n})$. This is a subsequence of $(a_n)$. Every subsequence of this tends to $\infty$ so it has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: I'm sorry sir. But can you explain it a little more. I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. Assume that $(a_n)$ is not bounded. Then for every $n$ there exist $a_{k_n}$ s.t. $|a_{k_n}|> n$. This way we constructed a subsequence that tends to $\infty$.